# Wix React Native Navigation - Navigate after async action

Tags: react-native, redux-thunk, react-native-navigation

I'm using Wix React Native Navigation and Redux Thunk. What's the correct way for navigating after an async action. I'm trying to do something like:

```
// actionCreators.js

export const createUser = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post('api/users', data)
            .then(() => {
              // Navigate to other screen.
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add extra code so your approach is clearer? Also, do you have access to `navigator.push`?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins I don't think so. If I understand correctly the `navigator` object is only accessible inside a component.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Your approach is ok on iOS but doens't work on Android.